# AngularJS How to Select and Initialise function on page load

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS

Objective:  How can I get All Categories (button)  To be highlighted and initialised on page load or refresh    (e.g. possibly using  ng-init or ng-options)

Controller

```
$scope.selectCategory = function(newCategory) {
  $scope.bottomValue = newCategory;
  selectedCategory = newCategory;
  $scope.selectedPage = 1;

}

$scope.categoryFilterFn = function(product) {
  return selectedCategory == null ||
    product.category == selectedCategory;
}

$scope.getCategoryClass = function(category) {
  return selectedCategory == category ? productListActiveClass : "";

}

$scope.getCategory = function(category) {
  return categorySelected == category;

}
```

HTML

```
<a ng-click="selectCategory()" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg" style="margin-bottom:6px">All Categories</a>



<a ng-repeat="item in data.products | filter:{edition:    data.editions[whichEdition].name}| filter:approved=true |  orderBy:itemOrder:direction | orderBy:'-category' | unique:'category' " ng-click="selectCategory(item)" class=" btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg"
ng-class="getCategoryClass(item)">
                {{item}}
</a>
```

Comment: what you mean by **To be highlighted and initialised**, can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using init function in controller rather than ng-init as init function is called before ng-init and I have everything ready to render.
In your view controller.

```
 $scope.init = function () {
//init fields and object
}
...
$scope.init();
```

Answer (score 2):

So whatever you want to do on page load , write a method in a single method like `$scope.init` and use call it like

```
<div ng-controller="controllerName" ng-init="init()">
```

this is , if you want to do everything on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Use anguls's  $window.onLoad.

```
$window.onload = function(param) {
  //your code here
  alert(param);
}
```

Or you can use ng-init directive with ng-controller -

```
<div ng-controller="yourController" ng-init="yourMethod(param)">
```

Here is yourController -

```
var app = angular.module('DemoApp', [])
app.controller('yourController', function($scope) {
  $scope.yourMethod = function(param) {
    alert(param.toString());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use Yauza said or you also can use ,,,,

`loadAllFunction()
function loadAllFunction(){
//Your code
}`